# How to re-scale probabilities based on new cutoff point?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, unbalanced-classes, scales

Suppose in a risk analysis study one component that needs to be estimated is probability of a binary event. We use a classification method, SVM for example, and achieve very good classification accuracy by adjusting the cutoff probability to, for example, 0.2 (instead of 0.5). Now, we want to use the probabilities (not predicted classes) in the risk analysis. Obviously, the non-scaled probabilities will not be useful (as 0.2 is our actual 50%). Is there a method to re-scale probabilities based on cutoff points?

Comment: Taking aside other things, the 0.2 cutoff is about your *classification decision*, it has nothing to do with probabilities being "incorrect". Say, your sample consists of 20% "successes", then the probability of "1" is 0.2, not 0.5. Other thing is that the scores returned by SVM are not well calibrated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not well calibrated"?

Comment: Many of the classifiers return some kind of scores, often in [0, 1], that are used to produce predictions. Those scores often are *not* optimized to produce correct estimates of probabilities (e.g. they are in logistic regression, but are not in many other algorithms), so you cannot treat the numbers as precise estimates of probabilities.

Comment: I assume it is the same for Random Forests too, as they are not actual probabilities, but ratio of votes. So is there a way to calibrate these scores?

Comment: See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html

Comment: Thank you. Your comments and the link were very eye-opening to me.